# Moto G5 Plus Screen Wake Problems

Tags: lock-screens, screen, motorola-moto-g5

Everything was working fine until about a week or two ago. Earlier, the screen would wake when I got a notification or if I titled my phone a little, the clock out show.

Now, my phone constantly wakes about every 10 seconds. It happens even when I'm not getting any notifications, or moving my phone at all. I don't know what's going on. I'm pretty sure this is causing some battery drain. How do I turn this off?! Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It may be a bug. Have you updated recently? If it is a heavy update/ os version. Moto recommend a factory reset.